# How to applying html/css on php loop functions

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I've been doing admin panel for property listing page using php,codeigniter, Html, CSS & Javascript using Bootstrap.

I'm done with basic design and function for my admin panel. But this time I want to explore more because my layout is not user friendly.

Example
I want to list a property so I have a lot of fields to fill-up. In my layout since I have a lot of fields I need to do scroll page.Check my sample screenshot[image]

As you can see my scroll bar is too long. So I'm thinking that I should use nav-tabs or like form wizard to save space for my page.

Anyone can have tutorial/tips on how to make formwizard or nav-tabs if you use `foreach/if else` function for your fields?

On my foreach I have CATEGORY and Fields.
So on each field have a parent.
Example:

**Facts (CATEGORY)**

-Purpose (Fields)

-Property type (Fields)

-Description (Fields)

**Building Info (CATEGORY)**

-Building Name(Fields)

-Amenities(Fields)

**Reference Code:**

```php
<?php foreach($options as $key_option=>$val_option):?>                                          
    <?php
    $required_text = '';
    $required_notice = '';
    if($val_option->is_required == 1)
    {
        $required_text = 'required';
        $required_notice = '*';
    }

    $max_length_text = '';
    if($val_option->max_length > 0)
    {
        $max_length_text = 'maxlength="'.$val_option->max_length.'"';
    }

    ?>

    <?php if($val_option->type == 'CATEGORY'):?>
    <hr />
    <h5><?php echo $val_option->option?> <span class="checkbox-visible"><?php echo form_checkbox('option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key, '   true', set_value('option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key, isset($estate->{'option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key})?$estate->{'option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key}:''), 'id="inputOption_'.$key.'_'.$val_option->id.'"')?> <?php echo lang_check('Hidden on preview page'); ?></span></h5>
    <hr />
    <?php elseif($val_option->type == 'INPUTBOX' || $val_option->type == 'DECIMAL' || $val_option->type == 'INTEGER'):?>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!$val_option->is_frontend && $this->session->userdata('type') == 'AGENT_LIMITED'?' hidden':'') ?>">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"><?php echo $required_notice.$val_option->option?> <?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?><i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="<?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>"></i><?php endif;?></label>
          <div class="<?php echo empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->prefix)&&empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->suffix)?'col-lg-9':'col-lg-6'; ?>">
            <?php echo form_input('option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key, set_value('option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key, isset($estate->{'option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key})?$estate->{'option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key}:''), 'class="form-control '.$val_option->type.'" id="inputOption_'.$key.'_'.$val_option->id.'" placeholder="'.$val_option->option.'" '.$required_text.' '.$max_length_text)?>
          </div>
          <?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->prefix) || !empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->suffix)): ?>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->prefix.$options_lang[$key][$key_option]->suffix?>
          </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif($val_option->type == 'DROPDOWN'):?>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!$val_option->is_frontend && $this->session->userdata('type') == 'AGENT_LIMITED'?' hidden':'') ?>">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"><?php echo $required_notice.$val_option->option?>  <?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?><i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="<?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>"></i><?php endif;?></label>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <?php
            if(isset($options_lang[$key][$key_option]))
                $drop_options = array_combine(explode(',',check_combine_set(isset($options_lang[$key])?$options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values:'', $val_option->values, '')),explode(',',check_combine_set($val_option->values, isset($options_lang[$key])?$options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values:'', '')));
            else
                $drop_options = array();

            // If you don't want translation to admin interface langauge uncomment this 1 line below:
            // $drop_options = array_combine(explode(',', $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values), explode(',', $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values));

            $drop_selected = set_value('option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key, isset($estate->{'option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key})?$estate->{'option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key}:'');

            echo form_dropdown('option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key, $drop_options, $drop_selected, 'class="form-control" id="inputOption_'.$key.'_'.$val_option->id.'" placeholder="'.$val_option->option.'" '.$required_text)

            ?>
            <?php //=form_dropdown('option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key, explode(',', $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values), set_value('option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key, isset($estate->{'option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key})?$estate->{'option'.$val_option->id.'_'.$key}:''), 'class="form-control" id="inputOption_'.$val_option->id.'" placeholder="'.$val_option->option.'"')?>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just make a div start and end in the foreach so each category gets its own div and assign it a name/ID based on the category name. Then make a separate foreach above the main one to just generate the nav tabs. Js will take care of the rest

Answer (score 1):

You can just use bootstrap tabs and then do something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // this will default the first tab to be shown
            $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
        });
    </script>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <?php foreach ($options as $key_option => $val_option): ?>
            <?php $item = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($val_option->option)); ?>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $item; ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo $item; ?>"><?php echo $val_option->option; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <?php foreach ($options as $key_option => $val_option): ?>
            <?php $item = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($val_option->option)); ?>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="<?php echo $item; ?>" role="tabpanel">
                <?php //echo $val_option->content; // or whatever?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

You need to include the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Bootstrap 4 requires popper js to work!

Comment: I follow your suggestion and I have title tabs but I having problem on showing content on each tabs when I click tabs it shows nothing.

Comment: You probably forgot to include popper.js. Check my updated answer, made a few other mods too.

Comment: Great answer, but we forgot the if else statement where we can identify which is a mytab(Categories) and mytabcontent(fields).

But this answer works fine with the different approach.

Comment: you mean a tab within a tab? i sort of missed that part. to be honest from a ux perspective that seems weird. i'd suggest just keeping it like facts, primary info, unit info as tabs and have the different fields within that.

Comment: Hmm. I have a front page like this  https://imgur.com/a/10UWD but i do this manually without using a loop or foreach. Then I notice my listing page https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmRey.png  is not good for a user who list/register because you will scroll too much.Then I'm thinking that I will do it like my front page but I having applying it on foreach.

Or if  you have any suggestion for better ux for my listing page?

Comment: No it looks pretty good, easy to find info from what I gather

Comment: I'm really curious about your db structure. Do you store the categories in a table and have the individual fields in a separate table with ids that relates to ids of the categories? I do something similar in that I have a class that gets all the fields in a table and by their type (varchar, text, .etc.) displays a certain type of input field, and if its an update it populates those fields. Makes changing things easier and I just have to update the db and the form updates as well.

Comment: My db structure is I created a table for my form types https://imgur.com/iJXny5r and another table for form name https://imgur.com/94ZF0z5

and relates the id's, example: **tb_1** parent_id relates  **tb_2**  id for form type  and  **tb_1* parent_id &  **tb_1* id for parent for each fields